# Django how can I redirect after post request result

Tags: python, django

```
def postDataRequest(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST['username']
            userid= request.POST['userid']
            if(userid== "21310"):
                context = {
                    "result" : Dataengine(username,userid).dataFunc()
                }
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, context)
                return render(request, 'pages/dataresult.html', context)
```

I show some data to users with post request.What I want to do is redirect `'pages/index.html'` within 30 seconds after the user sees the result on the `'dataresult.html'` page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template you can let the page redirect to a given URL with:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL={% url 'name-of-index-view' %}">
<link rel="canonical" href="{% url 'name-of-index-view' %}">
```

by adding that in the `<head>` compartment in the template that is rendered by the view that fires with the `dataresult.html` URL.

Comment: ValueError at /newdata/

The view aresbonus.views.postDataRequest didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.


I have an error with that

Comment: @Elfo: in your view, you only return something in case of a POST request, not a GET request, hence the error, but this has nothing to do with redirecting to a page here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **return redirect('app:view')** it will redirect you to the next view and if you want to redirect with **context** values then you can either

**1.from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect**

**return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:view', context))**

or

**2. redirect(reverse('app:view', context))**

because In django You can not pass parameters with redirect. Your only bet is to pass them as a part of URL.